# URL structure for structure section

Tags: structure

This seems like it should be straight forward. I need to set-up a structure section  with a parent page which uses the same section entry and same template. So the parent would have 'parent' as the slug and the children would have 'parent' as the first segment of the URL ie parent/children. Under the site settings in the section page I can include 'parent' before the slug, but this means the parent page gets the URL parent/parent. How do I get the parent page to keep the URL parent/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do this:

```
{parent.uri}/{slug}
```

You should get URLs like this:

- site.com/parent
- site.com/parent/child-1
- site.com/parent/child-2

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense! (This needs to be set in the site setting field of course)

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if it is correct. (I get karma points for this, which enables me to get the best parking spots downtown.)